# If Commands (CQRS) are actions of the UI, do they belong to Presentation Layer?

Tags: php, cqrs

Should I inject `Command` and `EventBus` in `Controller`, or should I inject `Domain Service` in `Controller`, and let `Domain Service` create the `Command` and dispatch to `Command Bus`?

Example:

```
// CreateUserController.php

public function __construct (CreateUserCommand $command, CommandBus $cm) {
   ...
}

public function createAction(Request $request) {
    // data validation
    $this->command->setData($request->getData());
    try {
        $this->cm->handle($this->command)
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return new Response(500)     // assume Response accepts http code
    }
    return new Response(200);
}
```

Or is it better having it call a domain service?

// CreateUserController.php

```
public function __construct (UserService $userService) {
   ...
}

public function createAction(Request $request) {
    // data validation
    $name = $request->getData()['name'];
    $lastname = $request->getData()['lastname'];

    try {
        $this->userService->createUser($name, $lastname)();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return new Response(500)     // assume Response accepts http code
    }
    return new Response(200);
}
```

This seems to be better because controller doesn't have the responsibility to populate a command and call the command handler, it simply validates that the required input is present via a Form, and then calls the Domain Service layer.

But then, if Commands belong to presentation layer, the workflow would be:

Presentation Layer (Request) -> Domain (Service) -> Presentation Layer (Command and Command Handler) -> Domain  -> Presentation Layer (Response)

Comment: We don't know. We have a very small snapshot of your project, certainly not enough to make a better decision than you can. So, I'm voting to close as "primarily opinion based".

Answer (score 1):

CQRS borrows a lot of ideas from [domain-driven-design](/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design).  When Eric Evans originally described DDD in [the blue book](http://a.co/b9L4npF), he was working from a three tier architecture: application/domain/persistence.

One key abstraction is the seam between the application and the domain, called the repository.  At that boundary, the interaction typically looks like

```
$user = repository->getById($id)
$user->create($name, $lastName)
repository->save($user)
```

Notice that all of the actual domain logic is hidden somewhere behind $user.

If you wanted to take that code block, and wrap it in a "service", that's fine.  But it would typically be considered to be an *application service*, rather than a *domain service*.  See Khorikov for an [overview of the distinction](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/09/08/domain-services-vs-application-services/) , or [Jimmy Bogard's take](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/).

A thing you may want to consider: commands, like http requests, are fundamentally *messages*.  Over the course of your applications lifetime, the definitions of those messages may change.  Something you'll want to think about is how many difference places you'll need to change code to [match the new message schema](https://leanpub.com/esversioning).

Comment: I added those in a Domain Service `UserService` under `Domain/Services`, with it contaning methods like `AddNew (name, lastname, email)`. The `UserService` constructor receives a `CommandBus`. The `AddNew` method creates a `Domain\Commands\User\CreateCommand` which is a DTO, and passes it to `CommandBus->handle()`. Then `Infrastructure\CommandHandler\User\DoctrineCreateHandler` receives a `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` in constructor, and `handle()` method uses the EntityManager to make the persist and flush operations.